If Shavuos and Shemini Atzeres are essentially the same holiday then why are their korbanos different?
The Midrash Rabbah (Shir HaShirim 7:2) equates Shavuos and Shemini Atzeres, calling them both Atzeres (shel Pesach/Sukkos), saying that really Shemini Atzeres should come later on in the year (similar to Shavuos), it is just that the inclement weather doesn't allow for it, see there.
Ramban too draws a comparison, terming the days from Pesach through Shavuos as chol hamoed (Vayikrah 23:36).
Pesach, Shavuos and Sukkos all share in the same basic korban format (Sukkos has certain additions), whereas Rosh Hashanah, Yom Kippur and Shemini Atzeres have a different set (Bamidbar 28-29).
My question is that if Shavuos and Shemini Atzeres are essentially the same holiday then why don't they share in the same korban protocol?

The Korban question (why is 8Atzeret korbanot more like RH/YK than Regalim) is fine already, there's no need for any of this Shavuot stuff

SA is in tishrei, as are RH and YK

Sukkot is more like tishrei korban + regel korban.

The comparison is that Shmini Atzeret is to Sukkot what Shavuot is to Pesach

Sforno's essay kavanos haTorah prefacing the Chumash says the default korban (Rosh Chodesh, Pesach, Shavuos) is 2 bulls, 1 ram, 7 lambs:

2 bulls: two ways to approach Hashem -- ahava and yir'ah.
1 ram: we emulate Hashem essentially in one way, kindness.
7 lambs: seven categories of mitzvos we perform.

High Holidays become 1/1/7 because the focus is on yir'ah, not ahava. Shmini Azeres 1/1/7, we are looking forward to the Messianic Era, all ahava no yir'ah.
The shtei halechem gets 1/2/7 because at the Sinai experience, it was all yir'ah; but we emulated Hashem in another way -- we'd briefly achieved immortality (till blowing it on the Golden Calf).
